# How to crop the Graphics?

Tags: graphics

I can get a `Graphics` object from a PDF file like

```
graphic=Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/article.pdf",{"PageGraphics",3}];
Head[graphic]
```

> `Graphics`

Then I crop it to get that table:

```
result = ImageTake[graphic,{70,300},{90,730}]
```

[image]

But note the head of `result` is changed into `Image`, It's not in **vector format** now

```
Head[result]
```

> `Image`

But I hope it keeps be `Graphics` still, is possible?

Comment: What gives  `Head[graphic]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann fixed

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates `Head[graphic] (*List*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann As I know, the `PageGraphics` is a new feature of 13

Comment: `ImageTake` takes an `Image` for the first argument.  If a `Graphics` expression is provided, it will be `Rasterize`'d first.

Comment: @ihojnicki So my question is how to keep the `Head`

Comment: You can arbitrarily wrap it in `Graphics` but that will not undo the rasterization step.  It's a bitmap now, not a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method visually crops the PDF page as a Graphics object, but the PDF page itself is not modified.  Suitable if the PDF page is not too bulky.

```
graphic = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/article.pdf",
   {"PageGraphics", 3}];
idim = ImageDimensions[graphic];
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {950, 310}],
  Inset[graphic, {Center, Center}, {Center, 650}, idim]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 950}, {0, 310}}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

Comment: This does something similar: `Graphics[graphic[[1]], PlotRange-> {{70,540},{580,720}}, PlotRangePadding-> 0, ImageMargins->0, ImagePadding-> None]`